# Why does this bash script show unexpected result?

Tags: bash

I have just started to learn shell scripting. I could not find an answer for this problem online.

The function given below takes an argument and checks if the length of string passed is non zero or not.

```
function length_checker {
    echo "number of arguments passed = $#"
    if [ $# -ne 1 ]
    then
        echo "Please pass an argument"
    elif [ -z $1 ]
    then
        echo "length of passed argument is zero"
    else
        echo "length of passed argument is non zero"
    fi
}

RANDOM_VAR='hello'
RANDOM_VAR2=''
length_checker $RANDOM_VAR2
```

Output:

```
number of arguments passed = 0
Please pass an argument
```

Problem:

since RANDOM_VAR2 is an empty string, and it is being passed in length_checker method, I was expecting the output to be "length of passed argument is zero".

However, it gives "number of arguments passed = 0".

I wanted to know how why is the argument not getting passed, and how to do so, such that it prints "length of passed argument is zero"?

Comment: Quote your variables. `length_checker $RANDOM_VAR2` is equivalent to `length_checker`. You wanted `length_checker ""` so you have to write `length_checker "$RANDOM_VAR2"`.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.